# How can I implement SalesForce custom RestAPI model binding?

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest

When implementing rest api methods in Salesforce, I often have to write code like this:

```
@HttpPost global static String CreateLead(
    String LastName, String Company, String Email, String Country,
    String State,String FirstName, String City, String Street, String Phone, String PostalCode)
        {
            system.debug('###### Attempting to create new lead');
            Lead l = new Lead();
            l.LastName = LastName;
            l.Email = Email;
            l.Country = Country;
            l.State = State;
            l.FirstName = FirstName;
            l.City = City;
            l.Street = Street;
            l.Phone = Phone;
            l.PostalCode = PostalCode;
            l.Company = Company;

            system.debug('######Attempting to insert lead');
            insert l;

            return l.Id;
        }
```

This is a little inefficient in that I have to specify each parameter. And in some cases I have to pass more parameters than possible for certain objects (36 parameter max). Is there a way to do something like...

```
@HttpPost global static String CreateLead(
        Lead MyLead)
            {
//do stuff 
}
```

And then from my external implementations just pass whatever JSON I want without throwing exceptions if parameters do not exactly match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can surely do that provided you have flexibility to marshall the incoming JSON

Lets take a simple JSON and see what happens

```
{
"MyLead": {
    "LastName": "TestAccount1",
    "Email": "msrivastav13@gmail.com",
    "Country": "India",
    "FirstName": "mohith"
}
}
```

Now let me draft the code for this as you wished and loved

```
@RestResource(urlmapping='/leadcreate')
 global class SampleRest{

 @HttpPost 
 global static String CreateLead(Lead MyLead){
   insert MyLead;
   return MyLead.id;
 }
}
```

Last bit is testing it up ,workbench REST Utility is God (Hate CURL )

[image]

Comment: The "MyLead:" was the answer! Thank you!